# Apache Nifi: Is there a way to publish messages to kafka with a message key as combination of multiple attributes?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have a requirement where I need to read a CSV and publish to Kafka topic in Avro format. During the publish, I need to set the message key as the combination of two attributes. Let's say I have an attribute called id and an attribute called group. I need my message key to be id+"-"+group. Is there a way I can achieve this in Apache nifi flow? Setting the message key to a single attribute works fine for me.

[image: publishKafkaRecord Processor]

[image: Flow]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the [`PublishKafka_2_0`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-0-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafka_2_0/index.html) (or whatever version you're using), set the **Kafka Key** property to construct your message key using [NiFi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html). For your example, the expression `${id}-${group}` will form it (e.g. `id=myId` & `group=MyGroup` -> `myId-myGroup`).

If you don't populate this property explicitly, the processor looks for the attribute `kafka.key`, so if you had previously set that value, it would be passed through.

#### Additional information after comment 2020-06-15 16:49

Ah, so the `PublishKafkaRecord` will publish *multiple messages* to Kafka, each correlating with a *record* in the single NiFi flowfile. In this case, the property is asking for a **field** (a [record term meaning some element of the record schema](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html)) to use to populate that message key. I would suggest using [`UpdateRecord`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html) before this processor to add a field called `messageKey` (or whatever you like) to each record using Expression Language, then reference this field in the publishing processor property.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using publishKafkaRecord_2_0 processor and there is a Message Key property that I am using to set the key. I tried the combination suggested and it publishes a null key. When I try with one field though (like just id), it works. Updated my question with the screenshot of the publishKafkaRecord processor

Comment: Thanks, This answer is a great help. One quick question: Can Nifi also make partitions on its own for my topic based on Message Key Attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Notice the (?)s on each property which indicates what is or isn't allowed:

[image]

When a field doesn't except expression languages, use an updateAttribute processor to set the combined value you need.  Then you use the combined value downstream.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to reference the inbuilt nifi attributes like uuid, filename, filesize, recordCount from the updateAttribute processor. How do I refer to the fields from my payload though? I am reading a csv file and when I try to refer to the attribute like ${id}, it does not work.

Comment: The simples form to get CSV values from content of flowfile to an attribute use SplitText -> ExtractText.  As suggested below, UpdateRecord can handle updating the CSV using a CSV Reader/Writer in which you tell nifi the schemas to use to read/write.  UpateRecord is preferred method.

Comment: Here is example of CSV -> SplitText, ExtractText, ReplaceText to PutSQL.   https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/NiFi-Templates   your flow would look similar but you would change the extracted values, how they are re-formed in replaceText, and then send to PublishKafka.     The other method is preferred as it can operate on the entire CSV,  vs the time to split it apart and process separate lines.

Comment: This discussion is not around record processing, so the _field_ in this case would not work. The property is expecting a record field name, not a compound Expression Language expression like most properties.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your inputs. I had to change my initial design of producing with a key combination to actually partitioning the file based on a specific field using PartitionRecord processor. I have a date field in my CSV file and there can be multiple records per date. I partition based on this date field and produce to the kafka topics using the id field as key per partition. The kafka topic name is dynamic and is suffixed with the date value. Since I plan to use Kafka streams to read data from these topics, this is a much better design than the initial one.

[image: Partition Record Processor]

[image: Publish Kafka Record processor]

[image: The topics are now named by date]

[image: Complete flow for reference]

Comment: Just note, it is not good practice to have more than 4K partitions per broker to avoid overhead of zookeeper.