# Set message key of Kafka topic from Apache nifi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have set up a simple pipeline in Apache Nifi that extracts some tweets from twitter and dumps them in a kafka topic. Tweets get dumped into the topic without an error but I can't figure out why the key of the topic message is not set.
I have used an "EvaluateJSONPath" processor to set the **attribute** of the flow file from the JSON extracted via the "GetTwitter" processor.
If I pause and see the queue that comes into "publishKafkaRecord" processor I can see the attribute set to be the key of the kafka message is there so this seems to work:
[image]

In my "publishKafkaRecord" processor I set the Message key field accordingly:
[image]

After running the flow file and looking at the contents of topic messages, every message has the **key** value set to null. Have I missed something important when configuring the processors?

UPDATE: Also tried to refference any of the other flow file attributes in the Message key property but the key is still set to null on every message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398284/apache-nifi-is-there-a-way-to-publish-messages-to-kafka-with-a-message-key-as-c

Comment: Since it's a label, not a path expression, try `${'kafka.key'}`

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [documentation for the PublishKafkaRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-6-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafkaRecord_2_6/index.html) processor you'll see that the Record processor does not get the key value from a FlowFile attribute, but a **field** in the Record.

> The name of a field in the Input Records that should be used as the Key for the Kafka message.
> Supports Expression Language: true (will be evaluated using flow file attributes and variable registry)

This is a little confusing, because it does mention that EL is supported - but it is still expecting the result of your EL to be a **field name** in the Record, from which it will get the value.

For example, you could set the `Message Key Field` value as `kafka.key` and it will look in each Record for a **field** called `kafka.key` and use it's value as the key. It is not looking for an Attribute.

Now, if you set `Message Key Field` to `${kafka.key}` it will look for an Attribute called `kafka.key`, and use the value of this Attribute **as the name of the field** within the Record that it should use.

For example, if you have an Attribute called `kafka.key` with a value `mykey`, and you set `Message Key Field` to `${kafka.key}`, then it will look for a **field** in the Record called `mykey` to use as the key for the message.

Thus, in your config, you not setting the key to `135792...etc.`, instead you are looking inside each Record for a **field** called `135792...etc.` and trying to use the value of that field as the key...Which is `null` because you don't have a field in your Record called `135792...etc.`.

So, you can use `UpdateRecord` before your `PublishKafkaRecord` - setting a field called `kafka.key` to the value of the Attribute `kafka.key`. Then change your `PublishKafkaRecord` to just `kafka.key`.

However, it sounds to me like you have 1 Record per FlowFile, so there is probably some optimisation that can be done to your flow, as Records are designed to be used with FlowFiles containing many Records.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, it's now perfectly clear to me. It's true that I have 1 record per FlowFile, so I decided to use PublishKafka instead of PublishKafkaRecord. I I was able to set the message key without any problems. Thanks again as I was stuck on this for days.

Comment: Thanks, This answer is a great help. I could easily set the message key for my records.  One quick question: Can Nifi also make partitions on its own for my topic based on Message Key Attribute + Default Partitioner.

Answer (score 0):

It did not work for me. The kafka key is still null and here is what I did for a demo purpose:

[image]

1. `GenerateFlowFile` produces a record with the future kafka key (i.e. 'metadata.aggregateId' field)
2. Used `UpdateAttribute` processor to add an attribute called 'kafka.key' with 'metadata.aggregateId' as its value
3. `PublishKafkaRecord` has its `Message Key Field` as ${kafka.key}
4. Produced Kafka message key is null
5. `LogAttribute` shows all necessary hooks are there

```
2022-02-19 17:57:40,401 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=e9b431f7-6784-1a90-8110-78386da99314] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=f495c59f-fdc6-4762-932e-f478a182039d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1645226154214-9, container=default, section=9], offset=36854, length=783],offset=0,name=f495c59f-fdc6-4762-932e-f478a182039d,size=783]
--------------------------------------------------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
        Value: 'Sat Feb 19 17:57:40 UTC 2022'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
        Value: 'Sat Feb 19 17:57:40 UTC 2022'
Key: 'fileSize'
        Value: '783'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'filename'
        Value: 'f495c59f-fdc6-4762-932e-f478a182039d'
Key: 'kafka.key'
        Value: 'metadata.aggregateId'
Key: 'msg.count'
        Value: '1'
Key: 'path'
        Value: './'
Key: 'uuid'
        Value: 'f495c59f-fdc6-4762-932e-f478a182039d'
--------------------------------------------------
{
  "metadata": {
    "aggregateId": "ABC123",
    "aggregateEventOrder": 2,
    "aggregateRepositoryId": "mdm@ABC",
    "aggregateType": "foo.bar.v1.BazType",
    "appId": "mdm",
    "businessKey": "ABC123",
    "correlationId": "aaaaaaa-403b-4856-a4d1-f07ff84064a6",
    "eventId": "bbbbbbb-c061-492e-a66a-9e63e2906e39",
    "eventType": "VIS",
    "eventMessageVersion": "1.0",
    "eventRecordedTime": 1519168559357,
    "qualifiedEventName": "foo.bar.v1.BazTypeChangedEvent",
    "userLoginId": 0,
    "userFirstName": "John",
    "userLastName": "Doe",
    "userLoginName": "app-abcd",
    "workBranch": "ABC",
    "changeType": "CREATE",
    "uploadNumber": "U38"
  },
  "data": {
    "_documentation": "simple demo data",
    "code": "ABC123",
    "description": "N/A"
  }
}
```

The original post and @Sdairs response made great sense to me.  What am I doing wrong here?  FWIW, I am using NiFi v1.12.1.